# MySQL ENUM to VARCHAR conversion issue

Tags: mysql, sql, enums, alter, mysql-5.7

I have a table `"temp_enum_test1"` with data type `"enum('IE','IS')"`. When I try to ALTER the table by changing data type into `VARCHAR` from 'ENUM', getting duplicate entry error. It is accepting records in `ENUM` type. Even when I query the table I am getting unique rows. Can anyone please help me here. Below are the schema and my approach.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE temp_enum_test1 (
    ->   r_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    ->   r_type enum('IE','IS'),
    ->   UNIQUE KEY uk_temp_enum_test1 (r_id,r_type)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.38 sec)

mysql> insert into temp_enum_test1 values(1,'IE');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> insert into temp_enum_test1 values(1,'IS');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> select * from temp_enum_test1;
+------+--------+
| r_id | r_type |
+------+--------+
|    1 | IE     |
|    1 | IS     |
+------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> alter table temp_enum_test1 change column r_type r_type  varchar(30);
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '1-I' for key 'uk_temp_enum_test1'
mysql>
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Using mysql 8.0

Comment: Ohh, But am using MySQL 5.7, It seems UK indexing for first character only for ENUM type am not sure about this.

Comment: Weird behaviour. It works fine if you remove the unique key, make the column change and then add the unique key back https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rBUVXxyWaneq4SpNJp4sdL/1

Comment: Thanks @Nick, I think I should go with this approach

Comment: @Vivek you should leave the question open. Someone who is more of an expert on MySQL might know the reason for it.

Comment: @Nick Sure I will keep this question open.

Comment: @Vivek Ironically I've just run into this exact problem myself, and I'm in a position where I can't remove the index first... Did you find an alternate solution?

Comment: @Vivek I did find this is a [known bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=89758) in MySQL 5.x; Based on reading that I found another workaround by changing the collation on the enum column first and then changing it back when changing the column to varchar. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=88d490d2020d41e18b139e028e9faa7b

Answer (score -1):

The problem seems to be with the create table query. The table has been created with 'UNIQUE KEY' that is causing the error while altering the table. If you can use

```html
PRIMARY KEY (`r_id`)
```

instead of ...

```html
UNIQUE KEY uk_temp_enum_test1 (r_id,r_type)
```

Complete CREATE command as below;

```html
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_enum_test1 (
  `r_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `r_type` enum('IE','IS') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`r_id`)
)
```

Comment: In actual scenario `r_id` can be duplicated

Comment: @vivek true that... the combination of r_id and r_type will always be unique because of the UNIQUE command used at the creation of table (i.e. UNIQUE KEY uk_temp_enum_test1 (r_id,r_type))